# How to dynamically generate a list of functions with a decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I have a series of functions in a module, for example

```py
def some_func1(param1, param2): pass
def another_func(param1, param2): pass
```

I would like the easiest way to add them to the list of called functions and then call some of them at a certain point by filter, with parameters. I tried to add to a list of functions using a decorator, something like this:

```py
all_func = {}

def decorator(filter):
    def function_decorator(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped

    all_func[filter] = function_decorator
    return function_decorator

@decorator(filter='1')
def some_func1(param1, param2): pass

@decorator(filter='2')
def another_func(param1, param2): pass

@decorator(filter='3')
def another_big_func(param1, *arg): pass
```

and then when using a loop using a filter, call the functions that match the filter:

```py
arg1 = some_obj
arg2 = another_obj
for i in range(3, 4):
    func = all_func.get(i)
    func(arg1, arg2)
```

That is, when adding a function, I simply prescribe a new filter value, not caring that I need to register something else somewhere, and then I call them on this filter

But something went wrong, at the time of `all_func.get (i)` I get a `function_decorator`, not a function, and I don’t understand how to call it with the given parameters.

I haven’t worked with decorators before, maybe I somehow misunderstood the concept.

Comment: do you mean like a macro record??

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t know what a macro record is. This code is part of a large python project and the required list of functions is passed to another class, where these functions will be called

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ: no, not like a macro.

Comment: Note that your `all_func` object is a dictionary, not a list, and you won't find your functions when using strings to register them then integers to look up functions. This may just be a translation error in creating your question, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You registered the *decorator*, not the wrapper. Note that what you named `decorator()` is really a decorator *factory*, calling `decorator(...)` produces the decorator function `function_decorator()`. Python then calls the `function_decorator()` function to do the actual decorating task, and its return value is used to replace the decorated function. You want to register the result of that process, not `function_decorator` itself.

Register the wrapper, `wrapped()`, instead:

```
def decorator(filter):
    def function_decorator(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        all_func[filter] = wrapped
        return wrapped
    return function_decorator
```

Now `all_func.get(i)` will return one of the `wrapped()` functions. Calling `wrapped()` then calls the decorated function, via the `func` reference.

Your `wrapper()` is really a no-op, so can be omitted. Decorators don't *have* to return a replacement function, the original function can be returned unchanged. Use the `func` reference to add to your registry:

```
def decorator(filter):
    def function_decorator(func):
        all_func[filter] = func
        return func
    return function_decorator
```

Note that you don't have a *list*, you have a *dictionary*, a mapping from key to value. Not that matters to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly unrelated (cf Martijn's answer for the core issue), but:

1/ `all_funcs` is a `dict`, not a `list`

2/ if you're using strings as keys when populating your dict (`@decorator(filter='1')`, you have to use strings as keys too to get your functions back (`range()` yields ints, not strings), so you want

```
for key in map(str, range(3, 4)):
    func = all_funcs.get(key)
```